# Nondegenrate symmetric bilinear form and subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space, and let $\langle \,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\, \rangle : V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ be a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form on $V$. For $u, v \in V$, let us define
$$ Q(u,v) = \langle u,u \rangle \langle v,v \rangle - \langle u,v \rangle^2 \in \mathbb{R}. $$
Let $W$ be a $2$-dimensional subspace of $V$. I want to show that the following three are equivalent.

(1) The restriction $\langle \,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\, \rangle|_W$ is nondegenerate.

(2) $Q(u,v) \ne 0$ for any basis $\{ u,v \}$ of $W$.

(3) $Q(u,v) \ne 0$ for some basis $\{ u,v \}$ of $W$.

Could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Hi :) Can you show (2) implies (3)?

Comment: I think it is the only trivial part.

Comment: This is equivalent to looking at the $2\times 2$ matrix $G$ where $g_{i,j} =\langle u_i, u_j\rangle$ (think Gram matrix) and stating $\det\big(G\big)\neq 0$.  The property of a determinant being non-zero does not change with change of basis (congruence transforms).  This result holds over any field, even characteristic 2 where notions of having an orthnormal basis need not apply.

Comment: I found that this is trivial if I use Sylvester's law of inertia, because $Q$ is the determinant as @user8675309 pointed out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(1) $\Rightarrow$ (3).** Let $\{u, v\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $W$ with respect to $\langle \,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\, \rangle|_W$ (it exists as it is non-degenerate), you have that
$$Q(u, v) = \|u\|^2\|v\|^2 \neq 0.$$

**(2) $\Rightarrow$ (3)**. Trivial.

**(2) $\Rightarrow$ (1).** By contradiction, let us assume that there exists $x \neq 0$ and $\langle \,x\,,\,z\, \rangle = 0$ for all $z \in W$. As $x \neq 0$ we can find a basis $\{x, u\}$ of $W$. By taking $z = u$, we deduce that $Q(x, u) = 0$.

**(3) $\Rightarrow $ (2).** Left as an exercise (it's not too hard, just take any basis of $W$ and develop it in term of the basis you have in (3)).

Comment: The point is that we can take an orthonormal basis! Thank you.